# One-liner to transform []int into string

Tags: go

Basically I have `[]int{1, 2, 3}`, I want a one-liner that transforms this into the string "1, 2, 3" (I need the delimiter to be custom, sometimes `.`, sometimes `,`, etc). Below is the best I could come up with. Searched online and did not seem to find a better answer.

In most languages there is in-built support for this, e.g.:

python:

```
> A = [1, 2, 3]
> ", ".join([str(a) for a in A])
'1, 2, 3'
```

go:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

// Could not find a one-liner that does this :(.
func arrayToString(A []int, delim string) string {

    var buffer bytes.Buffer
    for i := 0; i < len(A); i++ {
        buffer.WriteString(strconv.Itoa(A[i]))
        if i != len(A)-1 {
            buffer.WriteString(delim)
        }
    }

    return buffer.String()
}

func main() {
    A := []int{1, 2, 3}
    fmt.Println(arrayToString(A, ", "))
}
```

Surely there must be an utility buried into go that allows me to do this with a one-liner?

I know that there is `strings.Join(A, ", ")`, but that only works if A is already []string.

Comment: "I want to do this {without a loop, in one line, not using a slice, with this filesystem layout, whatever}." is somehow "un-Go-ish" as Go is heavily opinionated and the complete opposite of "clever". You have to process several things: Write a loop. You want to accomplish something difficult: Write several lines of code. You want to use the go tool: Stick to the workspace conventions.

Comment: If you've come here wanting to use a slice as a key to a map, just use `fmt.Sprint(arr)`, it is fast and works well.

Answer (score 164, accepted):

To convert
`A := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}`

to a one line delimited string like
"1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9"
use:

```
strings.Trim(strings.Join(strings.Fields(fmt.Sprint(A)), delim), "[]")
```

or:

```
strings.Trim(strings.Join(strings.Split(fmt.Sprint(A), " "), delim), "[]")
```

or:

```
strings.Trim(strings.Replace(fmt.Sprint(A), " ", delim, -1), "[]")
```

and return it from a function such as in this example:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "strings"

func arrayToString(a []int, delim string) string {
    return strings.Trim(strings.Replace(fmt.Sprint(a), " ", delim, -1), "[]")
    //return strings.Trim(strings.Join(strings.Split(fmt.Sprint(a), " "), delim), "[]")
    //return strings.Trim(strings.Join(strings.Fields(fmt.Sprint(a)), delim), "[]")
}

func main() {
    A := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}

    fmt.Println(arrayToString(A, ",")) //1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
}
```

To include a space after the comma you could call `arrayToString(A, ", ")` or conversely define the return as `return strings.Trim(strings.Replace(fmt.Sprint(a), " ", delim + " ", -1), "[]")` to force its insertion after the delimiter.

Comment: Nice regression indeed from a clean and simple ```a.implode(',')``` :-/

Comment: @LidelnKyoku php's `implode`, like python's `join`, allow one to do this in an easier way because they are **not** statically typed. I'm not sure it's easier than that in other statically typed languages

Comment: @arainone I wouldn't know, but IMHO it should still be (made) possible with some reduce feature or something, like so: `a.reduce((ret, item) => ret + itoa(item) + ',')` (to keep it simple, but not perfect)

Comment: All the proposed solutions are unnecessarily inefficient.

Comment: @InancGumus Could you please explain why?

Comment: @yogesh_desai If you use this function in a hot-path, you'll witness a lot of unnecessary allocations. Go is explicit and mostly one-liners are not Go style. When you bend idiomatic Go rules, it's inevitable to witness a lot of headaches later on.

Comment: I did test, this is very slow, better use a faster solution, if performance matters in your use case.

Answer (score 34):

I've just run into the same problem today, since I've not found anything on standard library, I've recompiled 3 ways to do this conversion

Create a string and appending the values from the array by converting it using strconv.Itoa:

```
func IntToString1() string {
    a := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    b := ""
    for _, v := range a {
        if len(b) > 0 {
            b += ","
        }
        b += strconv.Itoa(v)
    }

    return b
}
```

Create a []string, convert each array value and then return a joined string from []string:

```
func IntToString2() string {
    a := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    b := make([]string, len(a))
    for i, v := range a {
        b[i] = strconv.Itoa(v)
    }

    return strings.Join(b, ",")
}
```

Convert the []int to a string and replace / trim the value:

```
func IntToString3() string {
    a := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    return strings.Trim(strings.Replace(fmt.Sprint(a), " ", ",", -1), "[]")
}
```

Performance is quite different depending on implementation:

```
BenchmarkIntToString1-12         3000000           539 ns/op
BenchmarkIntToString2-12         5000000           359 ns/op
BenchmarkIntToString3-12         1000000          1162 ns/op
```

Personally, I'll go with IntToString2, so the final function could be an util package in my project like this:

```
func SplitToString(a []int, sep string) string {
    if len(a) == 0 {
        return ""
    }

    b := make([]string, len(a))
    for i, v := range a {
        b[i] = strconv.Itoa(v)
    }
    return strings.Join(b, sep)
}
```

Comment: Did you mean "SliceToString" instead of "SplitToString"?

Answer (score 15):

You can always `json.Marshal`:

```golang
data := []int{1,2,3}
s, _ := json.Marshal(data)
fmt.Println(string(s))
// output: [1, 2, 3]

fmt.Println(strings.Trim(string(s), "[]"))
//output 1,2,3
```

Comment: Is it possible to make it a one-liner?

Answer (score 5):

I believe that you can go with the `fmt.Sprint` family of functions. I am not expert in go formatting flags, and maybe you can make it with just a `Sprintf`, but here's a one-liner that works:

```
data := []int{1,2,3}

func(x string) string { return x[6:len(x)-1]; }(fmt.Sprintf("%#v", data)) // 1, 2, 3
```

In general, you could use `strings.Replace` to come up with different separators (as long as you can safely replace the `,` or  default separator):

```
// Produces 1--2--3
magic := func(s, d string) string { return strings.Replace(s[1:len(s)-1], " ", d, -1)  }
fmt.Println(magic(fmt.Sprint([]int{1, 2, 3}), "--"))

// As one liner
fmt.Println(func(s, d string) string { return strings.Replace(s[1:len(s)-1], " ", d, -1)  }(fmt.Sprint([]int{1, 2, 3}), "--"))
```

Comment: fmt.Println(fmt.Sprint(A)) yields `[1 2 3]`

This does not allow for a custom delimiter...

Comment: Precisely. Do you need *exactly* the "1, 2, 3" string?

Comment: Yes, making the question statement a bit more obvious that I need to control what is in between the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
    func convertIntToString(elems []int) string {
        b := ""
        for _, v := range elems {
           b += strconv.Itoa(v)
           b += ";"
        }
        return b
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

In case each value in []int is `uint8`, (aka. ascii), then you may create `[]byte`, then convert to string, then parse as int.

---

### Code

*(in `golang`)*

- []int to int

  ```
  // []int -> int, each int in []int is actually a byte,
  // for empty is will return error,
  func IntsToInt(is []int) (int, error) {
      bs := make([]byte, len(is))
      for i, c := range is {
          bs[i] = byte(c + '0')
      }
      return strconv.Atoi(string(bs))
  }
  ```
- Test case:

  ```
  import (
      "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
      "testing"
  )

  func TestIntsToInt(t *testing.T) {
      runOnce_TestIntsToInt(t, []int{1, 2, 3}, 123, false)

      // error, empty slice,
      runOnce_TestIntsToInt(t, []int{}, 0, true)
  }

  func runOnce_TestIntsToInt(t *testing.T, is []int, expectedResult int, expectError bool) {
      x, err := IntsToInt(is)
      if expectError {
          assert.NotNil(t, err)
      } else {
          assert.Nil(t, err)
          assert.Equal(t, expectedResult, x)
      }
  }
  ```

---

### Performance

- In my test, this is much faster than the `fmt.Printf()` versions from other answers.