# Converting array to csv

Tags: go

I have an array of different values - is there a way to convert it to csv string and output it via `fmt.Print` to stdout, without writing the csv to some file?

As far as I know, if I create a csv writer, I have to pass io file as a parameter, is there a way to just output it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [os.Stdout](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#pkg-variables) as your [io.Writer](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Writer).

Answer (score 11):

yes:
for string slice:

```
package main

import "encoding/csv"
import "os"

func main() {
    wr := csv.NewWriter(os.Stdout)
    wr.Write([]string{"test1", "test2", "test3"})
    wr.Flush()
}
```

for int (or any slice):

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    A := []int{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9} // []string{"test1", "test2", "test3"}
    st := strings.Fields(strings.Trim(fmt.Sprint(A), "[]"))
    wr := csv.NewWriter(os.Stdout)
    wr.Write(st)
    wr.Flush() // 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
}
```

another way:

```
package main

import (
    //"encoding/csv"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    A := []int{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
    st := strings.Trim(strings.Join(strings.Fields(fmt.Sprint(A)), ", "), "[]")
    fmt.Println(st) // 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
}
```

if your data is not int convert it to slice of string, then use strings.Join function.

and see:
[go / golang: one-liner to transform []int into string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37532255/go-golang-one-liner-to-transform-int-into-string/37533144#37533144)